# Python: Why is this the output when executed?

Tags: python, list, copy

Can someone tell me why, after I run the code below, these are the values the variables refer to now:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 5] 
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 5] 
x2 = [1, 2, 3] 
y = [1, 2, 3] 
y1 = [1, 2, 3] 
y2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Why isn't `y = [1, 2, 3, 5]` ?

And why isn't `x1 = [1, 2, 3]`?

Because, following this logic:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 3
b is still equal to 1, not 3.
```

Code is below. Thanks for your help.

```
def my_function(x, y):
    x.append(5)
    y = y + [5]


x = [1, 2, 3]
x1 = x
x2 = x[:]


y = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = y
y2 = y[:]


my_function(x, y)
```

Comment: You set `Y` to `[1, 2, 3]` and then want to know why it isn't `[1, 2, 3, 5]`? Are you kidding?

Comment: Did you scroll down to see the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement:

```
x1 = x
```

creates a copy of reference to the same list as pointed to by `x`. Now you are passing `x` to the function, where you append a value to `x`:

```
x.append(5)
```

this will affect the list pointed to by the original `x` outside the function, and eventually also reflect the modification for `x1`. Hence `x1` is `[1, 2, 3, 5]`.

---

Now, in case of `y1`, the only difference is this line in the function:

```
y = y + [5]
```

this line doesn't changes the original list referenced by `y` outside the function. It creates a local variable `y`, and initializes it to `[1, 2, 3, 5]`. But it doesn't changes the the original list referenced by `y` outside the function, and hence does not changes the list for `y1`. So, `y1` and `y` are still `[1, 2, 3]`.

---

You can verify it by checking the `id` of both the list inside the function, and the one outside:

```
>>> def my_function(x, y):
...     x.append(5)
...     y = y + [5]
...     return x, y   
... 
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x1 = x
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y1 = y
>>> 
>>> x2, y2 = my_function(x, y)
>>> 
>>> id(x2) == id(x)   
True
>>> id(y2) == id(y)
False
```

So, it's clear that `id` of original `x` is same as the one returned from the function. But the `id` of original `y` is not the same as returned `y`.

Comment: No idea who is down voting user's answers here. Thanks for your help though!
By the way, how do you know whether an expression does or doesn't affect outside the function? Do all methods, like pop and such, have an effect outside the function?

Comment: @Toki. You can mark the answer as accepted. You need to click on the arrow besides the answer to mark it accepted.

Comment: @Toki. Well, for one thing, when you change the reference to point to completely a brand new object, it won't affect the changes outside. Secondly, for mutable objects like `list`, if you modify something inside the list, the changes will be visible for all the references. You will gradually get comfortable with this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Mutable objects (such as lists) pass by reference, whereas immutable (such as integers) pass by value.

When you do `x1 = x`, `x1` refers to `x`; so any change to `x` also applies to `x1`, because **they refer to the same object**. `x.append(5)` changes the original `x`, and thus `x1` by reference.

However, when you do `x2 = x[:]`, you are copying the contents of the list by slicing it. Thus, you are making a **new** list.

When you do `y = y + [5]`, you are creating a new list in the function's scope. Thus, the global `y` (and `y1` by reference) remains unchanged. `y2` is just a copy of the original `y`, so the function does not affect it at all, either.

Comment: I'd give you an up vote if I could, but I need at least 15 reputation to do so. No idea who's giving down votes. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually change the reference of y you just set it to a different reference. This wouldn't actually change the y you passed in. Just the y in the local scope of my_function.

Step through it [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+my_function%28x,+y%29%3A%0A++++x.append%285%29%0A++++y+%3D+y+%2B+%5B5%5D%0A%0A%0Ax+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3%5D%0Ax1+%3D+x%0Ax2+%3D+x%5B%3A%5D%0A%0A%0Ay+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3%5D%0Ay1+%3D+y%0Ay2+%3D+y%5B%3A%5D%0A%0A%0Amy_function%28x,+y%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0)

Comment: Thanks for your help and for linking me to the visualizer! :)

Answer (score -1):

You're actually dealing with a question of scope here. At first it looks like you're having aliasing issues, but your redefinition of the variables passed in only lasts within the function. Once the function is done running, the arguments passed in (to put it simply) go back to their original values. It is only within the function that they continue to have the values you reassign them to. Try printing the odd outputs before the end of the function.

Comment: People are downvoting because they think the question is stupid. With a low rep of my own, I can't do much about it. Of course, if someone like F3AR3DLEGEND or someone else annoyed with the downvotes were to upvote me, I could put my vote toward remediating the issue. @Toki